# Why is my Dropdown overflowing even though I use the AutoSizeText widget on the hint text?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm attempting to make my DropDowns more responsive but I'm having issues doing that. I use the AutoSizeText widget on the text, but it still overflows. There is a little dropdown arrow at the end which could be causing it, but I'm not sure why it would be or how to resolve that. If anyone has some experience with this or can offer any advice I'd be very thankful! Thanks!

How it looks currently. Its overflowing which is bad. I just can't seem to get it to not overflow. I don't think the text is causing it

[image]

Heres the code for it

```
 stateDropDown() {
    return Container(
        child: Center(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
              child: FormField<String>(
                builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        color: Colors.white
                    ),
                    child: InputDecorator(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                          hint: AutoSizeText("Please Select a State or Province", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                          value: currentSelectedState,
                          isDense: true,
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              currentSelectedState = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          items: stateList.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution in a post. just had to add `isExpanded: true,`  to the DropDownButton

Comment: Better. This technically works but throws an error: `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.` I'm going to keep looking. UPDATE: Actually this works perfect if you use just `Text()` instead of `AutoSizeText()`

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping out the AutoSizeText widget for a normal Text() widget wrapped in a FittedBox widget with the scale down method..

```
FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
    child: Text(
        'Select State or Province', 
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    ),
),
```

Comment: Still overflows unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Try `maxLines:1` in **AutoSizeText** widget

```html
 hint: AutoSizeText("Please Select a State or Province",maxLines:1 ,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
```